# Concurrent session management always redirecting to failureurl - Java Config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I am using Spring MVC with Spring Security ver4.0.1.RELEASE.
I was trying to control the concurrent user login to 1 and show an error message if user already logged In. 
The Concurrent Session Management is working as expected but the expireUrl("") is not working. The .formLogin().loginPage("").failureUrl("") is always called instead of expireUrl(""). Please help.

Below is my SpringSecurityConfiguration.java which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/Access_Denied").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()      
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .failureUrl("/login?out=1")
    .usernameParameter("userID").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().csrf().and()
    .logout()
    .deleteCookies( "JSESSIONID" )
    .logoutSuccessUrl( "/logout" )
    .invalidateHttpSession( true )
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied.jsp")
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .maximumSessions(1) 
    expiredUrl("/login?time=1")
    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry);   
}
```

My Initializer class will looks like below -

```
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() };
}


public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
    servletContext.addListener(new CustomHttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

The below links provide extra info for this type of security configuration -

http://codehustler.org/blog/spring-security-tutorial-form-login-java-config/
https://gerrydevstory.com/2015/08/02/managing-spring-security-user-session/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move session management up on the chain?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/Access_Denied").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()   
    .and().sessionManagement()
    .maximumSessions(1) 
    .expiredUrl("/login?time=1")
    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry);   
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .failureUrl("/login?out=1")
    .usernameParameter("userID").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().csrf().and()
    .logout()
    .deleteCookies( "JSESSIONID" )
    .logoutSuccessUrl( "/logout" )
    .invalidateHttpSession( true )
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied.jsp")       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wermerb. The formLoging() is not defined for session management and hence this not possible :)